# 503 error while duplicate post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

While duplicate post in WordPress backend its showing Error 503 first byte timeout
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A 503 error means that the web server trying to be reached is unavailable - this could be because it is overloaded, down for maintenence, or not fully functional for another reason.

I've encounter 503 errors the time that my server is not much of load. I tried to avoid that problem by increasing the timeout in `vcl conf`

`first_byte_timeout = 300s;` (by default this is set to 60s)

For more information please check this out:

http://vincentfretin.ecreall.com/articles/varnish-guru-meditation-on-timeout

Hope it helps! :)